# Similar Triangles and Menelaus' Theorem

Tags: geometry

Let M be an interior point of the parallelogram ABCD. The parallel lines through M to the sides of the parallelogram intersect AB, BC, CD, and DA at Q, P, R, and N, respectively. Let point S be defined as the intersection of BN and DQ. Prove that points C, M, and S are collinear. [image]

So far I am trying to use similar triangles. I have that:

$\triangle DNS \sim \triangle DAQ$ by AA so $\displaystyle\frac{DN}{DA} = \frac{DS}{DQ} = \frac{NS}{AQ}$

$\triangle DSN \sim \triangle BSQ$ so $\displaystyle\frac{BS}{NS} = \frac{QS}{DS} = \frac{QB}{DN}$

$\triangle QSM \sim \triangle QDR$ so $\displaystyle\frac{QS}{QD} = \frac{QM}{QR} = \frac{SM}{DR}$

$\triangle NSM \sim \triangle NBP$ so $\displaystyle\frac{NS}{NB} = \frac{NM}{NP} = \frac{MS}{BP}$

I know to prove $C$, $M$, and $S$ collinear, to use Menelaus' C-M-S is the transversal. The two triangles I found with this transversal are $\triangle BNP$ and $\triangle RQD$, however I am having trouble proving those ratios to be equal to 1.

Comment: @dxiv I added what I have done so far to this problem. If anyone can assist me in what I should do from here I would appreciate it as I am stuck.

Comment: Do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Menelaus I would use Pappus' theorem for the collinear triplets $(DNV_{\infty})$ and $(BQW_{\infty})$ where $V_\infty$ and $W_\infty$ are the points at infinity of the sides of the paralellogram.

Answer (score 1):

Construction: Through M, draw TVMP // AB. Other extra parallel lines are similarly drawn.

[image]

Since DSQ is the diagonal of //gram AQRD and, in addition, SHAW and SKRU are the associated //grams, we have [//gram 1] = [//gram 2] + [//gram 3].

Similarly, from //gram TABP with diagonal TSB, we have [//gram 1] = [//gram 4] + [//gram 3].

∴ [//gram 2] = [//gram 4]

By the converse of the above fact, the last equality implies SMC is diagonal of the //gram USJC.